# Full Calendar- read keyboard arrow keys and derive same behavior as click on a date cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, keypress

I am trying to read keyboard arrow keys and derive the same behavior as a click on a date cell.

Non-working code is commented out, `gotodate` works, but simply implementing or decrementing date by one or seven does not cause date highlighting.

I want to both put the target date cell in focus, highlight it, and remove highlighting from the cell I have left.  I believe I don't understand or cant interpret the dayClick function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
                editable: true,
       defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end){
            //var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar  ('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: 'php/get-events.php',
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
                }

 });
$('#my-prev-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
});
   $('#my-next-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
});
// Hover states on the static widgets
$( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
    },
    function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
    }
);

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

            }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 33: // page up
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
                break;

                case 34: // page down
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
                break;

                case 37: // left
//     alert('left key pressed');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2015-01-19');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                break;

        case 38: alert('up key pressed');        
                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', 'days:-7');
                break;

        case 39:
        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', 'days:1');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate','2015-03-19');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

                                break;

        case 40: alert('down key pressed');
        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', 'days:7');
                break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
        });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[IncrementDate](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/incrementDate/) is expecting a moment.duration() object for second parameter, not the string to build a moment. You can see how to build a duration object [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

I think should work if you change

```
 //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', 'days:7');
```

To

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', moment.duration(7, 'days'));
```

Comment: Bravo, Signor Levrero:  You are correct, and the code now runs in the browser.  I still have the need to highlight the cell I have moved to.  color #bce8f1.  I tried  $( this ).addClass( "fc-highlight" ); but there is no effect.  The interpreter seems to understand the date (if I select via mouse the 20th day of the month and then press the up arrow key 3 times, it goes to the prior month on the third press, but I still can not get the day to highlight as it does on a mouse click.  Thanks for your effort.  I will uprate.

Comment: Welcome wills. About the highlight... Take a look at http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/

Comment: OK, I have progress this quite a bit over the past several days, with help from Mario.  There is a property of the moment date object _d which has the value I want  Date {Wed Feb 18 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)}  When I apply the format using var today = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('_d');      moment(today).format('yyyy-MM-dd');  I get the _i value for the default date instead - e.g. "2015-02-12" rather than the Feb 18 date. I can provide more of the code if that would be of value.  Thanks - all comments appreciated

Comment: Wills, I think your new question is out of the scope for this one. Maybe you should create a new question with your MomentJS problems. More people   can help you,

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for your help.  In case someone else would find it useful, here is a code segment of how it worked.  You have to access the _d property on the moment object.  Still more too do, but I am over that bridge.
                
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', moment.duration(7, 'days'));
       var j=$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
        var ja=j._d
        var k= moment(ja).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select',k);
      $('this').css('background-color', '#bce8f1');
     $('this').addClass( "fc-highlight" );
    break;